# How to move array list of values into different columns in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, arraylist, python-3.6

Hi i have a dataframe like

```
A
{1,2,3..1000}
```

I want to covert it into

```
A B C..ZZZ
1 2 3..10000
```

How can i split values in the array to different columns?

Comment: please make your initial state more clear. is A and {1,2,3} in a df?

Comment: A is column name and {1,2,3} is the values in the column

Comment: So my solution works.

Comment: your solution doesn't split the array into columns. I want every indexes into different columns@MhDG7

Comment: Vinauan: I updated my answer, I thought your array length is 3.

Comment: Do you run my code exactly? Cause I run it and it worked. Maybe there is difference between your A array and mine. I created it with range(1,1000)

Comment: sorry that was my  mistake@ MhDG7

Comment: So it worked finally?

Comment: No my array range is different in every column so it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Use [`df.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
import itertools
import string

names = list(
    itertools.chain(
        string.ascii_uppercase, 
        (''.join(pair) for pair in itertools.product(string.ascii_uppercase, repeat=3))
))


df = pd.DataFrame([[range(1,1000)]],columns=['A'])
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(df["A"].apply(pd.Series))).drop('A',axis=1)
df.columns=names[:999]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your df to be this:

```
In [924]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [{1,2,3}]})

In [925]: df
Out[925]: 
           A
0  {1, 2, 3}
```

You can do this:

```
In [935]: result = pd.DataFrame(df.A.tolist())

In [936]: result
Out[936]: 
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
```

Comment: my df is not like this A column has index upto 10,000. df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [{1,2,3...,10000}]})

Comment: It does not matter. It will break your column `A` into 10000 indices.

Comment: still the array not sliced into different columns @Mayank Porwal

Comment: What is the error you are facing in my solution? You can copy paste my solution and check.